# How to restrict Internet Explorer from maximizing my web application page when it was already minimized?

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, popups

I have a web application( CISCO Finesse) that works as a soft-phone. If I minimize my application page and if data is coming to the Finesse application by IVR application, that minimized IE window is maximizing automatically to show the call information in the application. But I want to keep the IE page always minimized.

Steps I followed:

1. *IE -> right click Properties -> Run -> Minimized*

[image]

2. Changing the REGISTRY setting also

Can anyone help me to fix this one?

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Cisco Finesse desktop interface manual](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/voice_ip_comm/cust_contact/contact_center/finesse/finesse_1001/user/guide/CFIN_BK_C1C095CD_00_cisco-finesse-agent-desktop-user/CFIN_BK_C1C095CD_00_cisco-finesse-agent-desktop-user_chapter_01.html),
section [Browser behavior](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/voice_ip_comm/cust_contact/contact_center/finesse/finesse_1001/user/guide/CFIN_BK_C1C095CD_00_cisco-finesse-agent-desktop-user/CFIN_BK_C1C095CD_00_cisco-finesse-agent-desktop-user_chapter_01.html#CFIN_RF_D7104F74_00),
there is no way to prevent IE from coming to the front or annoyingly
flashing on the taskbar, except by using more than one browser.

For IE, the manual says that no additional work is required for this
"feature" to work. Therefore do not use IE for Finesse.

For Firefox, the manual says that for this "feature" to work,
you need to change in `about:config` the value of `dom.disable_window_flip`
to `false`.

I would therefore try using Finesse in Firefox, after ensuring
that `dom.disable_window_flip` is set to `true`.

As the manual only describes IE and Firefox, while
Chrome is not mentioned, you could also experiment with it.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the same website, it appears that if you use Internet Explorer, you need to open a new blank tab in your Cisco Finesse browser screen, then minimize the screen.  This will cause it to just flash in the bottom of the tray but not pop up annoyingly in the middle of working on something.